# Razor generator application throwing error as view not found in main MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, razorgenerator

I'm new to the **razor generator**. I used razor generator in my mvc4 project and i'm sharing views using this app to my other mvc4 projects. 
I added reference of common project to my main project and I'm accessing views but it is throwing error as **view not found**.

Then **I added razor generator in my main project too and then it is working exactly as I want**.

**Now my issue is that if I'm adding razor generator in my common application then why I need to again add razor generator in my other MVC4 application ?**

Comment: Just to be clear: You are trying to share views between two different MVC sites?

Comment: @Maess : Actaully I want to create class librabry of views which I can use in different MVC sites. When I googled about my senario then I come to know about razor generator.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for the OP maybe....

Make sure the views are in "Views\Shared".

That was the only way I was able to get my main MVC project to find Razor Generator generated views in my library MVC project.